Azure AAD sign-in log IPs for ADFs do not match Public Azure IP Ranges
I have an app with conditional access turned on.  I'm getting the IPs of my ADFs to add them to the policy.  To find these IPs, I made a few sign in requests to the app from my ADFs, and looked in the sign in logs.
These sign in requests appeared in the AAD sign in logs with conditional access status as "failure", which was expected.  However, the IPs reported in the logs do not match exactly with any IP shown in the latest azure public cloud IP ranges reported here, which I expect it to.  My IP prefix is 20.42.3... which seems nonexistent in the file.
I'm looking for the accurate IPs of these ADFs to add them to the conditional access policy.  Which source can I trust, the AAD sign in logs or should I compile a list of all ADF IPs in the public azure IPs download link?
Thank you
